# Django: Verify email before creating a user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django project. I would like to verify email before creating a user account. What's the best way to do so? I decided to create an independent model first but I'm confused now.

I decided not to use allauth model because it's too complex. Instead, I'm generating a random number and sending it over email. Once the activation code is confirmed, a user should type a password. After obtaining a verified email and password, I need to create a User model. Email will be used as a username.

**EmailVerifyModel**

```
class EmailVerifyModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(help_text=_('A valid email address please'))
    isVerified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

**EmailVerifyForm**

```
class EmailVerifyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "type": "email",
        "name": "email",
        "id": "email",
        "placeholder": _("Email"),
        "class": "form-control form-control-md",
        "required": ""
    }), label = "")

    class Meta:
        model = EmailVerifyModel
        fields = ('email', 'activation_code')
        widgets = {
            'activation_code': NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Verification code'}),
        }
```

**View**

```
def signup_view(request):
    form = EmailVerifyForm(request.POST or None)
    email_verified = False
    
    if form.is_valid():
        
        new_email = form.save(commit=False)
        pin = randint(1000,9999)
        new_email.activation_code = pin
        new_email.save()

        cd = form.cleaned_data

        if not cd['activation_code']:
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = _('Verify Your Email')
        
            email_body = render_to_string('email/verify-email.html', {
                        'domain': current_site.domain,
                        'token': pin,
                    })
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, email_body, 'no-reply@test.com', ['test@test.com'])
            msg.send()
            email_verified = True

        elif cd['activation_code']:
            email = EmailVerifyModel.objects.get(email = form.instance.email)
            print('user with email', email)


    return render(
        request,
        'signup.html',
        {
            'form': form,
            'email_verified': email_verified, 
        }
    )
```

Comment: Instead of managing multiple models, just add a separate `BooleanField` called something like `is_verified` to the User model and set it to True once the user has verified the email with the steps you want to use. And then make sure the value is True on every login.

Comment: there is such field already in default django `User` and its called `is_active` but you'd be forced to use `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = 
 ('django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend', )` but its just chaning 1 line of code so shouldnt be to hard

Comment: @quqa123 good point

Comment: @Johan will try that approach, thx